# Why do we make a dipole a ideal dipole?

Tags: electrostatics, dipole, dipole-moment

My question is that why do we make a dipole a ideal dipole ($q\to\infty$ and
$d\to 0$) …i mean i want the reason behind to take this and what is the problem of taking a charge with some magnitude (not approximately equal to infinity) and distance between them having some magnitude (not approximately equal to zero)??

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion

Comment: Your question is not particularly well framed, and the grammar and usage errors really detract from it. I suggest improving your question.

Comment: We tend to see 'ideal' dipoles in nature, for example - atoms or molecules

Comment: @Sid Ideal dipoles are often adequate models of atoms and molecules, but there's always more complexity if you dig.

Comment: @JohnDoty I think they were asking why we consider that case at all, so I gave a simple example.

Answer (score 3):

Because a non-ideal dipole has higher order moments. See: Multipole expansion.

Really, it's the same reason we use plane waves, which are a single frequency, but require infinite temporal and spatial extent as such.

There are no perfect plane waves in reality, but be use them as idealizations for simplicity. An electromagnetic plane wave is described (up to normalization, ignoring polarization) by one thing: a wave vector $\vec k$.

Meanwhile, a multipole moment is completely described by $(l, m)$.

To summarize: these are the egien-solutions to the problem that are easily described by eigenvalues in the canonical domain, while in the spatial domain, they are either extended, apparently complicated, or both.

Same for atomic orbitals...what simpler: $n, l, m$ or Laguerre polynomials multiplied by spherical harmonics?

Comment: Too much complicated answer

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason that we use points, lines circles, etc. to model physical objects. Nothing is truly point like, there is nothing perfectly straight, there are no perfect circles, ... We use these things because they capture relevant features of physical situations without distracting us with the inevitable extra complexity of reality.

In the case of an ideal dipole, it is useful to model a field configuration whose geometry doesn't depend on scale. If I take a pair of charges and measure the field far away, the direction of the field has very little dependence on distance. But close to the charges, the field is more complicated. It's often useful to build models using an ideal dipole field, where the field direction has *no* dependence on distance, and the extra complexity disappears.

Answer (score 0):

This may be confusing since something like a "perfect circle" we can imagine; whereas two charges being bought infinitely close together is not even imaginable because it would require an infinite amount of energy.

The "ideal" dipole does *not* have that $q\to \infty$ and $d\to 0$ but instead that these are finite! -- You are mistaken in thinking that we take limits of these values. The product is what matters: $p = qd$ is called the dipole moment and appears in the electrostatic formulas.

We are *not* saying that the ideal dipole has infinitesimal separation or anything like that.

So what makes it ideal? Well we are thinking in the *far field*. I.e. we are assuming that our measurement point $r \gg d$ so that we can neglect terms in the expansion of two $\Phi = \pm \frac qrt$ potentials.

Answer (score 0):

I would add to John Doty's answer that from the standpoint of radio engineering, the "ideal dipole" is useful as a reference standard against which to compare the performance of real-world dipoles, and that modeling an antenna as an ideal dipole gets you pretty close to the right answer when building your own antenna.